# How to print the object details to a file?

Tags: scala

To print each object to a file I use this code :

```
def printToFile(f: java.io.File)(op: java.io.PrintWriter => Unit) {
  val p = new java.io.PrintWriter(f)
  try { op(p) } finally { p.close() }
}

printToFile(new java.io.File("c:\\csvfiles\\clean.csv"))(p => {
    myObjectList.foreach(p.println)
})
```

How can I access the objects within myObjectList and print their attribute values ? Do I need to overrride the toString method of the object or is there an alternative method ?

Comment: Case classes get an automatically supplied `toString` override that shows the class name and primary constructor parameters within parens. It's minimalistic, but serviceable.

Comment: OP: In this case, overriding toString may not be ideal because it would tailor the output to csv format; this can become an issue when more formats are necessary. And in general, having an concise and readable toString on an object is better than use it for specific format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
myObjectList.foreach{ ob => p.println({
  /* Do whatever you need to do with ob that produces a string */
})}
```

as long as whatever it is you are doing will work for the type that the collection thinks that it contains.  Otherwise, overriding `toString` is probably the best solution.